# What exactly the word afraid means for Americans?

Tags: american-english, british-english

There's a platform where I asked a American gamer girl if the game she is playing on PlayStation available for PC? She replied something like no it's not available, I'm afraid. I don't remember exact wordings as she said it veritably.

In my country afraid means *scared*; someone would use it when they are scared.

For example, "My girlfriend was afraid after watching a horror movie." In this sentence she is scared after coming out of theater but when that American gamer said I'm afraid it was a different meaning. Can anyone explain this please with a context, when exactly Americans use the word afraid?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial attempts at research. Looking up all the meanings of *afraid* in a quality dictionary should answer your question.

Answer (score 7):

Though the primary meaning of *afraid* is to have fear, a very common use is

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/afraid :

> 2. (colloquial) regretful, sorry
>
>    *I am **afraid** I cannot help you in this matter.*

This usage is common in both American and British English.

The phrase is commonly used as a politeness marker, and is often interchangeable with *unfortunately* or *sorry to say*.

Comment: Please don't answer questions which ELL, intended for simpler questions, would consider under-researched. Providing answers invites further such questions which are expressly discouraged on ELU.